# How to use Spotify API to find path between two artists

Tags: spotify-app

I am trying to mimic this
site :http://boilthefrog.playlistmachinery.com/index.html
source code:  https://github.com/plamere/BoilTheFrog

What I can do:
Use Spotify API to do queries and searches.

Problem:
How to build a graph that can find the path between the two artists